# Navigating multiple relationships in MVC EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Just starting to work with EF and can't figure out if I'm thinking incorrectly or am I just missing something simple.

[image]

I'm trying to get Institution, SendRule and and CrimeType information that is linked to SendRule in one window.

In Controller, I pass to model data like so:

```
var institution = await _context.Institution
.Include(i => i.Rules)
.ThenInclude(r => r.SendRule)
.ThenInclude(c => c.CategoriesToSend)
.ThenInclude(cr => cr.CrimeType)
.AsNoTracking()
.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.InstitutionID == id);
```

And in View, I display everything like so:

```
<dt>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
</dt>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>Rule Name</th>
    <th>Cron</th>
    <th>Categories</th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model.Rules)
{
<tr>
    <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SendRule.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SendRule.Cron)
    </td>
    <td>
    @foreach (var item2 in Model.Rules)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelThing => item2.SendRule.CategoriesToSend)
    }
    </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

But from item2.SendRule.CategoriesToSend I can't navigate to CrimeType. Is it because its many-to-one relationship? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jesus I'm dumb. instead of

```
@foreach (var item2 in Model.Rules)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelThing => item2.SendRule.CategoriesToSend)
}
```

It should have been

```
@foreach (var item2 in item.SendRule.CategoriesToSend)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelThing => item2.CrimeType.Description)
}
```